# Is there an end to the game "The Void"?

Tags: pc, the-void

I've put far too many hours into [The Void](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Void_%28video_game%29) and have not seemingly gotten very far.  I've read a couple reviews where the reviewers admitted that they have not played the game all the way though.  Is there a real end to this game, and a return to life?

Comment: I'm sure this is something to do with the game but you're worried about "returning to life" then I would suggest you step away from the TV for a little bit lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personally couldn't get very far with this game without applying [this difficulty patch](http://forum.ice-pick.com/viewtopic.php?p=101816#p101816), and a walkthrough. Rest assured that there is an end to it, though.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the accepted answer: **yes, there are a number of different endings in fact.** While they are all rather similar, they involve different characters. The conditions for the different endings are as follows:

1. Survive until the end of Cycle 35 and do not save a Sister.
2. Reach Turgor and draw Breakthrough on a sister (there is a slightly different ending for each sister).
3. Reach Turgor and draw breakthrough on the Nameless Sister's tree and then on the Nameless Sister. This requires a lot of colour and is the most difficult ending.